# create private key from ECDSA public key

Tags: cryptography

Public ECDSA Key Hex :

> 04d6597d465408e6e11264c116dd98b539740e802dc756d7eb88741696e20dfe7d3588695d2e7ad23cbf0aa056d42afada63036d66a1d9b97070dd6bc0c87ceb0d

Public Address:

> 12ib7dApVFvg82TXKycWBNpN8kFyiAN1dr

How to calculate its private key?

Comment: I don't have a technical answer (try Crypto.SE or Security.SE) but in short, you cannot. I mean, **that's the whole point** of an asymmetric system – it only goes one way.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. If you could, it would break down asymmetric encryption. The point of asymmetric encryption is to have a key pair with one public key, and a private key. The private key should not be disclosed. It would make no sense to be able to derive the private key from the public key.

Comment: Ok, is it possible to convert Private key into WIF format